# Сервис parse.com: Использование значения ключа в качестве имени класса

Tags: javascript, parse.com

Например, в post-запросе присутствует ключ `OClassName`, значение ключа - имя одной из таблиц в БД. Цель - получит через `request.params` значение ключа `OClassName` и запросить с БД весь список записей из этой таблицы.

---

Что пытаемся достичь - *одна функция на сервере, которая вернет список записей указанного класса*.

---

Код:

```
var className = request.params.OClassName;
...
var query = new Parse.Query(className);
...
```

---

По итогу: возвращается ошибка, не совсем уверен в том, что в переменную className вообще что-либо попадает. Если сам способ достижения цели, указанной выше, в принципе не верен, прошу, объясните.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/276135/ переезжайте

Comment: Спасибо, уже ) Я мигрировал с Parse.com на DigitalOcean, теперь там все вертится. Так что вопрос все еще актуален.